# How to use 'Replace' function in SalesForce SOAP API in C#

Tags: api, soap, c#

I am using SalesForce SOAP Enterprise WSDL API in my C# application.
What I came across is the need to use the `SELECT` query which includes `REPLACE` function.
I tried Developer Console>>Query Editor by executing the following query, but it's giving me

> Unknown error parsing query

Following is my query that I want to execute :

```
`SELECT Id, Name, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, office_phone__c.replace("-",""), phone_fax__c FROM Contact`
```

I also tried in the following way, but that's also giving me the same error.

```
`SELECT Id, Name, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, REPLACE(office_phone__c,'-',''), phone_fax__c FROM Contact `
```

As the query implies, I want to replace `"-"` in my `office_phone__c` field with `""`.

Has anyone used such type of query before.
I would be very grateful if anybody can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query like that.

Query with the normal office_phone__c field. Then when using the field value in your code replace the - with '' at that time.

Comment: You meant to say that SalesForce doesn't support `replace`  function at all in the query? But what if I have to select many fields of these types. This is just a single example that I gave for ease of understanding. Actually my query contains around 5 to 6 such fields and I want to replace characters like `(`, `)`, `-` and ` `

Comment: There is no replace function that you can use directly in a SOQL query. You have first query the data and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The SOQL language does not support any function like a "REPLACE" function. You best bet is to query for the data, and then later in your code, you can replace the values. An alternative is to use a forumula fields which replaces the value and you query the formula fields instead of the actual fields.